# python : extract sub string after delimiter

Tags: python

I would like to extract sub string from initial string at the last occurrence of delimiter:

example

```
str1= "aaaa.{i}.bbbb.{i}.cccc.{i}."

str2= "aaaa.bbbb.{i}.cccc.{i}."

str3= "aaaa.bbbb.cccc.{i}."
```

the expect result is:

> cccc

I use the following python script:

```
res = str3.rsplit('.{i}.', 2)[1]
print(res)
```

but for the `str3` the script doesn't show the expected result `cccc` !

Comment: It's a funky delimiter. On `str3` you do not have another `.{i}.` that splits the string in the location you want. It seems that instead, you want to split the string via the delimiter `.` and then (or... before) remove the occurrences of `.{i}.`.

Comment: Do you really want `cccc` as output in all three cases? It should be clear to you that this is impossible with splitting by one delimiter. Maybe you didn't make clear enough what your actual problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to `(r)split` all three strings just once and get the result `'cccc'` in all cases. I guess you know that, but you didn't correctly translate your idea into Python.

You may `rsplit` twice:

```py
>>> str1.rsplit('.{i}.')[-2].rsplit('.')[-1]
'cccc'
>>> str2.rsplit('.{i}.')[-2].rsplit('.')[-1]
'cccc'
>>> str3.rsplit('.{i}.')[-2].rsplit('.')[-1]
'cccc'
```

or use regex:

```py
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'^.*\.([^.]+).{i}.$')
>>> re.match(pattern, str1).group(1)
'cccc'
>>> re.match(pattern, str2).group(1)
'cccc'
>>> re.match(pattern, str3).group(1)
'cccc'
```

While I'd expect the regex solution to be far less efficient than the double split approach, but I didn't measure. I also didn't do any error handling.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like:

```
str1= "aaaa.{i}.bbbb.{i}.cccc.{i}."

str2= "aaaa.bbbb.{i}.cccc.{i}."

str3= "aaaa.bbbb.cccc.{i}."


def last_occur(st):
    st = st.split('.{i}.')
    st = list(filter(None, st))
    return st[-1]
```

This will also remove empty strings in case you have only one split.

Result:

```
last_occur(str1) --> cccc
last_occur(str2) --> cccc
last_occur(str3) --> aaaa.bbbb.cccc
```

Comment: OP seems to expect `cccc` as output for all tree strings. We know this is not possible by just splitting...

Comment: I see,
So probably need some regex here.

Comment: ...or you split twice

Comment: I think what you do is the right thing if we take description and title more serious than the allegedly expected output. But all this looks quite contradictory to me...

Comment: *This will also remove empty strings* -- I think this deserves a bit of clarification. `filter(None,...)` isn't really self-explanatory